# How do I hide fields thats rails admin shows when I create a new model (user)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I'm going to create a new user, rails admin shows me many fields like `created_at`, `sign_in_at`, etc, etc etc.

Comment: maybe you can elaborate? Paste code what you have in the form. What have you tried etc.

Comment: `config.model 'User' do
    list do
      field :name
      field :ci
      field :center
      field :solapin
      field :email

      field :encrypted_password
      field :faculty
    end
  end`

Comment: and this modify the show list, but when im going to add a new user continue showing me all the fields

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `create` instead of `list` in the config block.
Enter the following code in `config/initiazlizers/rails_admin.rb`.
See https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields for further details regarding the customization of fields.

```
 config.model 'User' do
    create do
      field :name
      field :email
      # etc....
    end
  end
```